# How to sort an instance with day/month/years stored in a vector without using the copy function

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm in an intro C++ class and we were tasked with creating a program to take data from a file regarding the weather, input it into an array, then sort it in descending order (where the most recent data is in the array's first index), and output it.

I can get my sort function to work for the years, but once the year is the same and you're sorting by month is where I'm having trouble. And to add even more fuss, we haven't learned the sort() function yet so we are not allowed to use it in the code.

I've attached what I have so far, but be warned it's pretty sloppy and not commented. This is because it's to be submitted online in chunks of code, where sometimes the rest of a bit of code is written for us. I've done my best to piece it together, but some things may not make sense/be out of order. My sortData function is at the bottom, and I've got my most recent attempt at a solution still in there. It doesn't work, obviously, but maybe it'll lend to how I'm trying to go about this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct WeatherData {
   int day;
   int month;
   int year;
   int clouds;
   double temp;
   double wind;
   string watch;
};

class WeatherStation {
private:
    vector<WeatherData> m_data;
public:
    WeatherStation();
    int getNumData();
    WeatherData getData(int);
    void sortData();
    void addData(const WeatherData&);
};

int main() {
   string line;
   string file_name;

   cin >> file_name;

   //Weather variables
   int day, month, year, clouds;
   double wind, temp;
   string watch;

   WeatherStation station;
   istringstream sin;
   ifstream fin;
   string watchLine;

   fin.open(file_name.c_str());

    if(fin.fail()) {
        cout << "Could not open file.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while(getline(fin, line)) {
        sin.clear();
        sin.str(line);
        sin >> day >> month >> year >> clouds >> temp >> wind >> watch;
        getline(sin, watchLine);
        watch = watch + watchLine;

        WeatherData data;
        data.day = day;
        data.month = month;
        data.year = year;
        data.clouds = clouds;
        data.temp = temp;
        data.wind = wind;
        data.watch = watch;

        station.addData(data);
    }

    station.sortData();

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < getNumData(); i++) {
        cout << "Weather data for " << station.getData(i).month << "/";
        cout << station.getData(i).day << "/";
        cout << station.getData(i).year << ": ";
        cout << "Temp: " << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << station.getData(i).temp;
        cout << ", Wind: " << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(3) << station.getData(i).wind;
        cout << ", Clouds: " << station.getData(i).clouds;
        cout << "\nNotes: " << setw(28) << right << station.getData(i).watch << "\n\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

int WeatherStation::getNumData() {
    return m_data.size();
}

WeatherData WeatherStation::getData(int index) {
    return m_data[index];
}

void WeatherStation::addData(const WeatherData& data) {
    m_data.push_back(data);
}

void WeatherStation::sortData() {
    int i, j, k, l, firstYear, firstMonth;
    WeatherData tempData;
    for(i = 0; i < m_data.size(); i++) {
        firstYear = i;
        for(j = i + 1; j < m_data.size(); j++) {
            if(m_data[j].year > m_data[firstYear].year) {
                firstYear = j;
            }
            else if(m_data[j].year == m_data[firstYear].year) {

                for(k = 0; k < m_data.size(); k++) {
                    firstMonth = k;
                    for(l = k + 1; l < m_data.size(); l++) {
                        if(m_data[l].month > m_data[firstMonth].month) {
                            firstMonth = l;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        if(firstYear != i) {
            tempData = m_data[i];
            m_data[i] = m_data[firstYear];
            m_data[firstYear] = tempData;
        }
        else if(firstMonth != k) {
            tempData = m_data[k];
            m_data[k] = m_data[firstMonth];
            m_data[firstMonth] = tempData;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you've learned about classes and declaring methods, I'd declare a dead-simple (probably all `const` fields) "date" type with a "less than" (`isBefore`?) method (or operator).  This would greatly simplify your actual sorting code, since it abstracts the comparison to the type that know how to deal with it.  The power of a function isn't necessarily code reuse (as some courses tend to point to), but _abstraction_, so you no longer have to deal with certain things.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I'm submitting this online, and the instructions are very direct in what I need to write. For example the first parts were telling me to create my struct and class and what variables/functions they needed to contain. So unfortunately this "block" that it's asking me to create is ONLY the sortData function. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, in which case you might want to elaborate a bit more because I'm not sure I fully understood what you were trying to say.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Would you be allowed to create an additional function just to compare the date portions of two lines?  eg `bool isBefore(const WeatherData& a, const WeatherData& b)`?  Otherwise, keep in mind you don't usually need to _remember_ what the date was, just know if it was before whatever it was compared against.  ....I'm a little torn about recommending looking up existing sorting algorithms, or playing along with the instructor and expecting you to do it yourself (usually students end up with bubble sort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your variable name from `firstYear` to `latestDate` you might find it clearer. `firstYear` makes you think you only have a year to work with, but you have the entire `WeatherData` structure to work with instead.

You don't need a third inner loop (your `k` loop in your current code) - you can compare the year, month, and day for each item as you check it.

So you can do

```
if(m_data[j].year > m_data[latestDate].year) {
    latestDate = j;
}
else if(m_data[j].year == m_data[latestDate].year) {
    if(m_data[j].month> m_data[latestDate].month) {
        latestDate = j;
    }
    else if(m_data[j].month == m_data[latestDate].month) {
        ... do the same for day
```

Ideally you would encapsulate this in a member function of `WeatherData` or even as a standalone compare function which takes two `WeatherData`objects, but you can leave it in the sort method if that is what is required by the task.

Comment: Wow, that makes so much sense. Thank you so much! Changing the var name to latestDate definitely helped--good tip.